# Cannot install Spket in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, extjs4.1

I want to use Spket in Eclipse for my extjs4.1 project. I found there are lots of installation tutorials, saying that:

In eclipse, click Help >> Install New Software, type "http://www.spket.com/update/"

But after that, a window pops up and says "No software site found at http://www.spket.com/update/".

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can install spket via update site - [spket](http://www.agpad.com/update/)